# Got the new Blender 4.0 (this time portable), but it still stores all the addons and preferences like a regular version in App Data

Tags: interface, customization, settings

It`s Win 10. I copied Blender foundation folder to the D drive and pointed it the preferences but doesnt give a damn. Any ideas pls?
[image]